# Converting AppleScript to SwiftAutomation

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, applescript

This AppleScript that I found here does what I want:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set matchtrack to tracks in playlist 1 whose persistent ID is "C70EA9CDC276CB6D"
    if matchtrack is not {} then
        return name of item 1 of matchtrack
    else
        return "no track found"
    end if
end tell
```

That is, finds a track based on the persistent ID. I'm trying to get it to work in a MacOS Cocoa Swift application using the [Swift Automation](https://bitbucket.org/hhas/swiftae) as an Apple Event Bridge. I can retrieve the value with:

```
let trackID = try iTunes.tracks[1].persistentID.get()
```

I've tried all sorts of statements. This one seems to show the most promise:

```
let trackRow = try iTunes.tracks[ITUItem.persistentID == "C70EA9CDC276CB6D"].get() as ITUItem
```

When I run it, I get the error:

```
Instance member 'persistentID' cannot be used on type 'ITUItem'
```

The framework is in beta at the best so it may be a bug. Any suggestions on what else to try? I'd ask the author, but I can't find a way to contact him.

Here is part of the sdef file that was generated by the app.

```
item n : an item
    properties
    class_ (type, r/o) : the class of the item
    container (specifier, r/o) : the container of the item
    id (integer, r/o) : the id of the item
    index (integer, r/o) : The index of the item in internal application order.
    name (text) : the name of the item
    persistentID (text, r/o) : the id of the item as a hexadecimal string.   This id does not change over time.
    properties (record) : every property of the item
```

Track is a subclass of item.

### Fix

When I first tried @matt's suggestion of ITUIts.persistentID, it wouldn't compile. I got the error:

```
Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ITUItem' and 'String'
```

After some back and forth, I realized the problem was that I was missing an import:

```
import SwiftAutomation
```

I had it in originally and wasn't sure I needed it so I commented it out. A dozen other calls to it worked fine without it before I got to this one.

Comment: For `ITUItem.persistentID` put `ITUIts.persistentID`. See documentation here: https://hhas.bitbucket.io/object-specifiers.html

Comment: It didn't work. See above.

Comment: It does work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ITUIts` and get rid of `as ITUItem`. So:

```
let trackRow = try itunes.tracks[ITUIts.persistentID == "C70EA9CDC276CB6D"].get()
// result will be something along these lines:
// [ITunes().sources.ID(66).libraryPlaylists.ID(93639).fileTracks.ID(95018)]
```

Herewith, a complete working test along with the results on my machine (of course your numbers will be different):

```
let itunes = ITunes()
let trackID = try itunes.tracks[1].persistentID.get() as String
print("track ID is", trackID)
// track ID is 689006177BB39343
let trackRows = try itunes.tracks[ITUIts.persistentID == trackID].get() as [ITUItem]
if let trackRow = trackRows.first {
    print(trackRow)
    // ITunes().sources.ID(66).libraryPlaylists.ID(93639).fileTracks.ID(95018)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sticking with it. I cut and pasted your code into my viewDidLoad function in my NSViewController and I get the same error as above. I'm running the latest version of Swift. The controller only imports Cocoa. It work fine with a number of other calls for data. I've never changed my compiler options. The SwiftAutomation package/framework is in a work space with my prototype app that does nothing other than run this code. And I've read the doc several times.

Comment: I also removed the as [ITUTtem] in your code without effect.

Comment: Well, I don't know what you want me to do short of sending you a movie of me running the code. I assure you that it works on my machine. I wrote it directly into the _main.swift_ file of the "test" target of the SwiftAE project downloaded directly from https://bitbucket.org/hhas/swiftae. If you'd like to post your project somewhere like github, I'll be happy to download it and see if I can work out what's amiss.

Comment: I got it to work. It was the missing import SwiftAutomation. It's strange that a dozen other called compiled and functioned without it. Thanks for putting in time on it.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I do wish you'd take the rather insulting "@matt's suggestion of ITUIts.persistentID won't compile:" stuff out of the question.